# Proper sizes for Background Image/NagivationBar Image iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface

I'm wondering what the correct sizes are for

1) setting a background image for a UIView on various iPhone devices, including Retina, 4s, 4, etc..

(does the version of iOS matter?)

2) setting a background image for the UINavigationBar, again on those various device versions/os versions

Lastly, how should one go about naming these files. I know that Apple is very strict about naming an image with a @2x.png, with specific names, etc.

If there is documentation that somebody could point to, that would be great as well. I couldn't find anything on the dev website...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you at least check the [User Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH1-SW1) (particularly, the [Custom Icon and Image Creation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW1))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***iPhone and iPod Touch Screen Pixel and UI Component Dimensions***

Notes:

Retina Dimensions are given in parentheses.

All pixel dimensions include highlight or stroke effects.  For example, a 30-pixel high button is actually a 29-pixel high button with a 1-pixel highlight on the bottom.

*iPhone screen size:*

Portrait 320×480 (640×960) pixels
Landscape 480×320 (960×640) pixels

*iPhone Nav bar:*
Portrait: 44 (88) pixels high
Landscape: 32 (64) pixels high

*iPhone Nav bar buttons:*
Portrait: 30 (60) pixels high
Landscape: 24 (48) pixels high

*iPhone Nav bar button icons:* About 20×20 (40×40) pixels (when in Landscape mode, it shrinks the 20×20 (40×40) pixel icon)

*iPhone Toolbar:* 44 (88) pixels high (does not change)

*iPhone Toolbar button:* 30 (60) pixels high (does not change)

*iPhone Toolbar button icon:* about 20×20 (40×40) pixels

*iPhone Tab Bar:* 49 (98) pixels high (does not change)

*iPhone Tab Bar icon:* about 30×30 (60×60) pixels

***iPad Pixel Dimensions:***

*iPad screen size:*
Portrait 768×1024 (1536×2048) pixels
Landscape 1024×768 (2048×1536)

*iPad Navigation Bar and Tool Bars:* 44 (88) pixels high

*iPad Nav Bar and Tool Bar buttons:* 30 (60) pixels high

*iPad Nav Bar and Tool Bar button icons:* about 20×20 (40×40) pixels

*iPad Tab Bar:* 49 (98) pixels high

*iPad Tab Bar icons:* about 30×30 (60×60) pixels

*iPad List View:* 320 (640) pixels wide.

Follow answers in [this link](http://www.vigorouscoding.com/2012/03/naming-conventions-for-image-resources-in-ios/) for the basic naming standards for the newer devices. iOS version shouldn't matter, but hardware does.

**EDIT**
Wow, literally found all dimension [on this site](http://www.gameartguppy.com/iphone-ipad-basic-screen-component-dimensions-updated-for-retina/) Check it out, it has pictures!

Another useful link [here](http://www.gameartguppy.com/useful-image-resizing-apps-for-ios-developers-designers/).